# Update statement causes fields to be updated with NULL or maximum value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

If you had to pick one of the two following queries, which would you choose and why:

```
UPDATE `table1` AS e
SET e.points = e.points+(
SELECT points FROM `table2` AS ep WHERE e.cardnbr=ep.cardnbr);
```

or:

```
UPDATE `table1` AS e
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT points, cardnbr
   FROM `table2`  
) AS ep ON (e.cardnbr=ep.cardnbr)
SET e.points = e.points+ep.points;
```

Tables' definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `cardnbr` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `points` decimal(7,3) DEFAULT '0.000',
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user@company.com',
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=25205 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `cardnbr` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `points` decimal(7,3) DEFAULT '0.000',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci$$
```

UPDATE: BOTH are causing problems the first is causing non matched rows to update into NULL.
The second is causing them to update into the max value 999.9999 (decimal 7,3).
PS the cardnbr field is NOT a key

Comment: I would go for the second, as it is more readable.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if performance would be quite the same, due to internal query optimization of MySQL. Anyway, I'd prefer using joins because imho it's nicer.

Comment: Can you provide the tables' definitions?

Comment: More important, is `cardnbr` the primary key of `table2`?

Comment: And maybe the values in `table2.points` (when added) are more than `9999.999` for some `cardnbr`. That would explain the behaviour.

Comment: @ypercube no matter what values of points, non matched rows will give either 9999.999 or null depending on the query and if the points is set to not null or not. I tried points NOT NULL at first and i still got more matched rows then in table2 and values were altered!

Comment: Show us some sample rows, before and after the Update is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the two statements are not equivalent, as you found out yourself. The first one will update all rows of `table1`, putting `NULL` values for those rows that have no related rows in `table2`.

So the second query looks better because it doesn't update all rows of `table1`. It could be written in a more simpel way, like this though:

```
UPDATE table1 AS e
  INNER JOIN table2 AS ep
      ON e.cardnbr = ep.cardnbr
SET e.points = e.points + ep.points ;
```

So, the 2nd query would be the best to use, if `cardnbr` was the primary key of `table2`. Is it?

If it isn't, then which values from table2 should be used for the update of table1 (added to `points`)? All of them? You could use this:

```
UPDATE table1 AS e
  INNER JOIN
  (  SELECT SUM(points) AS points, cardnbr
     FROM table2  
     GROUP BY cardnbr
  ) AS ep ON e.cardnbr = ep.cardnbr
SET 
    e.points = e.points + ep.points ;
```

Just one of them? That would require some other derived table, depending on what you want.

Comment: I want to select all the values from table2 and update the corresponding rows at table1. cardnbr field is not key in both and identical in nature.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the second one..reason for that is

When using `JOIN` the databse can create an execution plan that is better for your query and save time whereas subqueries (like your first one ) will run all the queries and load all the datas which may take time.

i think subqueries is easy to read but performance wise `JOIN` is faster...